# Categorical definition of the characteristic of a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, category-theory

The [characteristic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_%28algebra%29) of a [ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_theory) is an important algebraic concept (and a specific number), but it refers to *elements*, so - in my understanding - it is *evil* (from the point of view of category theory). So the question arises:

> How is the *characteristic of a ring* defined and calculated categorically?

Given the [category of rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_of_rings), how is the characteristic - as a number - of its objects calculated:

- from their in- and outgoing arrows?
- from special functors?
- from or to which other categories?
- or what ever?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A ring $R$ has characteristic 0 iff the morphism from the initial object $Z$ of the category of rings is a monomorphism. In general the morphism $Z\to R$ factors (in unique way) as $Z\to P\to R$ where $Z\to P$ is a regular epi and $P\to R$ is mono. The characteristic of $R$ is just this morphism $Z\to P$, if you will.

Comment: Or, better, the characteristic of $R$ is the kernel of the unique homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \to R$.

Comment: @ZhenLin Certainly -- but what do you mean by kernel in the category of rings?